# Is there a way to disable the annoying device performance alert while debugging in android?

Tags: android, debugging, android-5.1.1-lollipop

Is there a way to disable the annoying device performance alert while debugging in android (Android 5.1.1)? 
While in breakpoint the phone declares my app as "persona non grata" counting the number of times it "crashed", claiming it's slowing my device...
It just might, ONE DAY :)

The problem is that it stops my debugger too. Is it because I am still using eclipse, and not Android Studio?

Didn't find any option in the settings to disable this...

[image: what the OP is seeing...]

Comment: You may wish to take a screenshot of what you are seeing, upload it somewhere, and link to it from your question. I have never seen anything, in an IDE or on a device, that is "counting the number of times it 'crashed'". If you are seeing this on the device, then it is probably something peculiar to that particular device manufacturer or model, but having a screenshot would help us to confirm that theory.

Comment: Samsung Galaxy S6 G920F [screen capture](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2ddwgyIdrm2MU1GX1VNVGxYSzg/view?usp=sharing) <<--- here

Comment: Amazing that "nobody seen" is the response :) I was sure it's going to be all over the internet by now... Probably a Samsung only feature?

Comment: Just saw that it complains on "auto open" that the app has. I do have a number of services running under the hood... Could be that is the reason this message is uncommon?

Comment: I have never seen that dialog before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That window comes from the "Smart manager" app pre-installed in recent Samsung ROMs. It can't be easily disabled or deleted without rooting, but these commands did the trick on my Galaxy S6:

```
adb shell pm hide com.samsung.android.sm
adb shell pm hide com.sec.android.service.sm
```

Comment: Yepp I found out too that it is something to do with the app optimizer which comes with the Galaxy S6...